# How to take a photo of a glass-covered screen so that all scratches are easily visible?

Tags: macro

I'm going to put up my phone for sale on an online auction so I'd like to take a picture of the front screen showing future buyers exactly how many scratches are present. What is the easiest way of achieving what I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up your light source that it is at a very sharp right angle to your phone, I.E. the light is skimming across the face of the phone. Then look at the phone from the position of the camera which should be facing straight at the phone and look to see if you see the scratches. You may have to adjust the light source a little until it is just right.

You are setting it up so the light skims across the surface of the phone and just catching the edge of the scratch but the light is not shining down into the deep part of the scratch, this creates a shadow and contrast between the well lit surface of the screen and the deep valley of the scratch.

The position of the light is also dependent on which directions the scratches are running, try to position the light so that it at a right angle to the majority of the worst scratches.

You will need to turn off all other room lights so they do not fill in the  shadows you have created.

also the phone should be off.

Comment: Works best if the screen is reflecting, from the camera's perspective, a dark surface to maximize contrast and make the scratches more visible. You don't have to work in the dark—just position the phone and/or a dark surface so you can see it in the glass. This is independent of the position/direction of your light source.